# Call another Lambda and pass through parameters a function that returns a set of information

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-3.9

I'm currently developing a lambda that invokes another Lambda with Boto3. However, I need from one statement to retrieve a group of results and send them through the invoke payload to the other Lambda.  However, I can't find how to send this function as a parameter to call another Lambda and pass through parameters a function that returns a set of information.

I have implemented this method:

```py
from MysqlConnection import MysqlConnection
from sqlalchemy import text

    def make_dataframe(self):
        conn = MysqlConnection()
        query = text("""select * from queue WHERE estatus = 'PENDING' limit 4;""")
        df = pd.read_sql_query(query,conn.get_engine())
       
        return df.to_json()
```

This is the Lambda handler:

```py
import json
import boto3
from MysqlConnection import MysqlConnection
from Test import Test


client = boto3.client('lambda')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    mydb = MysqlConnection()
    print(mydb.get_engine)
    df = Test()
    df.make_dataframe()


    
    object = json.loads(df.make_dataframe())
    

    response = client.invoke(
        FunctionName='arn:aws:lambda:',
        InvocationType='RequestResponse'#event
        Payload=json.dumps(object)
        
        )
        
    

    responseJson = json.load(response['Payload'])

    print('\n')
    print(responseJson)
    print('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is correct in terms of structuring your call.
I assume the problem is with your payload structure and whether its stringified.
I would try invoke your lambda with an empty payload and see what happens. If it works with empty payload then its your payload serialising, if it doesnt work with empty payload then its something else.

In cloudwatch what do your logs of both your "runner" lambda and your "target" lambda say?

It might also be a permissions thing - you will need to specify and grant execute permissions on your runner lambda.

Comment: The empty payload works, but when the function is called, it sends the error Syntax error in module I attach the log

Comment: Function Logs
START RequestId: 0c72a4fc-be94-464d-9a7f-c23e93d81fec Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 25)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py" Line 25
      Payload=json.dumps(objeto)END RequestId: 0c72a4fc-be94-464d-9a7f-c23e93d81fec
REPORT RequestId: 0c72a4fc-be94-464d-9a7f-c23e93d81fec Duration: 38.54 ms Billed Duration: 39 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 37 MB Init Duration: 107.74 ms

Comment: It you create a variable equal to the payload you're trying to send and print it out does it look right?

Comment: If it's saying syntax error then you probably have a spelling or syntax error. The line you posted says Json.dumps(objecto). Is it objecto? Or object?

Answer (score 0):

after days of refactoring and research I am sharing the answer. It is about packing the json.dump object and inside the handler place the method with the response already packed

This a method to parent child
class Test:

```
def make_dataframe(self):
    conn = MysqlConnection()
    query = text("""select * from TEST WHERE status'PEN' limit 4;""")
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query,conn.get_engine())
    lst = df.values.tolist()
    obj = json.dumps(lst, cls=CustomJSONEncoder)

    return obj

def lambda_handler(event, context):
mydb = MysqlConnection()
df = Test()

response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='arn:aws:lambda:',
    InvocationType='RequestResponse',
    Payload= df.make_dataframe()
    )

responseJson = json.load(response['Payload'])
print('\n')
print(responseJson)
print('\n')
```

`